# .htaccess redirect non-www to www except for a particular subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all example.com to www.example.com except for example.com/subdirectory which should remain as is without any redirection.

Comment: Do you want to do this w/o using PHP, etc?

Comment: I am open to using a PHP script to do this. I used to have a website that was running on my server but i have moved the website to google sites. www.example.com dns points to my google sites website.
i have only one part of the website which is in the local server in the folder subdirectory and example.com dns still points to the local server. Hence i want everything else that is not in subdirectory to point to google sites which is www.example.com/*

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by having the following in the .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]